# how to proof the convergence of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove the convergence of this series :
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\biggl(\frac{1}{3n^2+4n+1}\biggl) = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{12}}$$

Comment: "How to know which test I should chose when proving the convergence of a serie ?" Experience, and enough persistence to try again and again after each test fails. In this specific case, alternating series test is probably easiest, but ratio test should also work nicely. As for _finding_ the limit once you've proven that it exists, that's a different story altogether.

Comment: [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Comment: use the alternating series test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series is absolutely convergent: comparison with $\sum 1/n^2$.
I presume you really wanted to ask why it converges to $\pi/\sqrt{12}$.
Well,
$$\frac2{3n^2+4n+1}=\frac{3}{3n+1}-\frac1{n+1}=3\left(\frac1{3n+1}
-\frac1{3n+3}\right).$$
Your sum equals
\begin{align}
\frac32\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n
\left(\frac1{3n+1}-\frac1{3n+3}\right)
&=\frac32\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_{0}^1(t^{3n}-t^{3n+2})\,dt\\
&=\frac32\int_0^1\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^3}\,dt\\
&=\frac32\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{1-t+t^2}\,dt.
\end{align}
This is an integral one can do via standard calculus methods.

Answer (score 0):

the alternating series test consists of proving that $$|a_n|$$ is monotonous decreasing and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$$ the secont part is clear, for the first part we have $$a_{n+1}-a_n=-{\frac {6\,n+7}{ \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 3\,n+1 \right)  \left( n+
2 \right)  \left( 3\,n+4 \right) }}
<0$$ for $n>0$

Comment: There are easier ways to prove $a_{n+1}<a_n$, for instance by proving that $1/a_{n+1}>1/a_n$.